# Can i place slip in a wave like pattern?

Tags: cricket

Can i place slip in a wave like pattern?
Can i place first slip ahead of keeper towards batsman instead of behind the keeper? 
I have not seen these types of fieldings.

Comment: As answered in your other question, you can place fielders wherever you like. You probably haven't seen them because they're not a good idea, not because they're forbidden by the laws.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but if I was 1st slip I'd refuse to stand where you suggested. The ball comes fastest to first slip, and the extra distance is to allow the player to react.

To answer your question, there are no restrictions preventing you from doing it, just logical reasons why it doesn't happen.